# Not able to run git submodule init with gradle war plugin

Tags: java, ant, gradle

My `build.gradle` looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

war {

   ...

}
```

I build using `gradle war`

In the configuration phase, I want to run `git submodule update --init --recursive`

so I changed my build.gradle to:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

task configured(type: Exec) {
  commandLine "git submodule update --init --recursive"
}


war {

   ...

}
```

when I do `gradle war`:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':war'.

I do not see my submodules being updated. What is wrong?

EDIT:

I put following line in settings.gradle

```
exec {
  commandLine "git", "submodule", "update", "--init", "--recursive"
}
```

I removed task configured from build.gradle.

Do you thing thats a good solution??

Answer (score 1):

> In the configuration phase, I want to run git submodule update --init --recursive

Your current build is doing this in the execution phase. Why do you want to do it in the configuration phase? Note that this will slow down every single invocation of Gradle.

> I do not see my submodules being updated. What is wrong?

Only tasks specified on the command line and their task dependencies will be run. If you don't specify `configured` on the command line, nor make (say) `war` depend on it, it won't be run.

> What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':war'.

Apparently there is some problem in the remainder of your build script (which you didn't show). Perhaps you were trying to do something like `war.dependsOn(configured)`, and didn't get it quite right.

Comment: Please see my comments above as EDIT

Comment: That's a step in the wrong direction. If you really want to, you can put that code into `build.gradle`. However, it will slow down every single Gradle invocation (even, say, `gradle tasks`).

Comment: Of course it depends on whether the Git submodule contains a `settings.gradle` or `build.gradle` for the current build. If it does, things will get more complicated. It would help if you explained the bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve.